# Unable to connect to minikube when using WSL

Tags: windows, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, wsl-2

I am testing out a kubernetes cluster on my Windows machine using minikube. I installed minikube on Windows via chocolate and I have a script to access it from wsl2. I also have installed kubectl on wsl2.

```
#!/bin/sh
/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/minikube.exe $@
```

I was able to create deployments for my client and server and I can view my pods using `kubectl get pods`

```
$kubectl get pods

NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
client-chart-deployment   1/1     Running   0          35m
server-chart-deployment   1/1     Running   0          35m
```

Since I am using a LoadBalancer service for my client and server I used `minikube tunnel` to connect to them.

```
$minikube tunnel

�  Starting tunnel for service server-chart-service
�  Starting tunnel for service client-chart-service
```

I was also able to create services for both deployments and I can view those with `kubectl get serviecs`

```
$kubectl get services

NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
client-chart-service   LoadBalancer   10.99.57.135    127.0.0.1     3000:30741/TCP   37m
server-chart-service   LoadBalancer   10.109.66.209   127.0.0.1     4000:31539/TCP   36m
kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          4d21h
```

I can also view everything from `minikube dashboard` and `minikube service list` gives me the following

| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | server-chart-service | 4000 | http://192.168.49.2:30963 |
| default | client-chart-service | 3000 | http://192.168.49.2:31381 |
| default | kubernetes | No node port |  |
| kube-system | kube-dns | No node port |  |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper | No node port |  |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard | No node port |  |

However, after everything is set up and running, I am still unable to connect to my client or server services at http://127.0.0.1:3000 and http://127.0.0.1:4000 through my browser and through curl.

I also tried the http://192.168.49.2:30963 and http://192.168.49.2:31381 and those do not work as well.

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an issue in WSL2. Check these two GH Issues:

- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4199
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5298